# desendant child operator '>' not always working

Tags: css, css-selectors

Check this out:

```
<div class="Root">
<div>direct child 1</div>
<div>
    <div>indirect child 1</div>
    <div>indirect child 2</div>
</div>
<div>direct child 2</div>
</div>

.Root > div {
color:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N5qFu/86/

It's not working properly. But If instead of color, I change the border, it works.
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is it "not working properly"? Remember that `color:` is an inherited property. If you want to exclude it then do this:

```
div div { color: black; }
.Root > div { color: green; }
```

Comment: Why is it that colors are inherited but borders aren't? I mean why does it make sense that some attributes be inherited but others not?

Comment: @user1316459: Why do you think it makes sense that borders should be inherited?

Comment: Why do you think it makes sense that colors should be inherited?

Comment: @user1316459 If you've ever set the color on the body element, you've relied on the fact that color is an inherited property.  Body is not some magical element that descendants inherit styles from:  some properties are specifically set to inherit regardless of the ancestor in question.

Answer (score 2):

[Because the default color value is `inherit`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-color)

http://jsfiddle.net/N5qFu/87/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="Root">
    <div>direct child 1</div> <!-- this div is being colored -->

    <div>     <!-- this div is being colored! still a direct child-->
        <div>indirect child 1</div> <!-- color is being inherited -->
        <div>indirect child 2</div> <!-- color is being inherited -->
    </div>

    <div>direct child 2</div> <!-- this div is being colored -->
</div>
```

The wrapper `div` is still a direct child.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of color is inherit. I [updated your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N5qFu/88/) with the following code first:

```
div {color:black;}
```